# Python2.7 Crypto.PublicKey.RSA how to encrypt a string and get another string (and not a tuple)

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, rsa

When I ecrypt a string with Crypto.RSA, the output is a tuple.
I'm working on a networks projects (secure group chat), and the because the output is a tuple:

1. I convert it to a string
2. I send it over a socket
3. I use literal eval to get the tuple back
4. I use sk.decrypt(cyphertext) on the tuple I got from the eval

I have seen on the RSA docs that decrypt can take a bytestream as it's input, so
my question is how do I convert the tuple I get from the pk.encrypt(message) to a bytestearm that can be decrypted by sk.decrypt(cyphertext).

also when I create the key, what size do you think I should use for it?
Im currently using 256 * 12 which is 3072.

PyCrypto docs: https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#encrypt

Comment: But it says the tuple consists of (encrypted_data, None). So the encrypted_data is just the first element of the tuple. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @JamesKPolk My bad then, I didn't notice it. What key size do you think will be alright for a chat?